# How can I find SATA driver for LG 15U560-KA51K laptop?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop, drivers, sata

I've got a LG laptop 15U560-KA51K which was made in December 2015. Originally Windows 10 was installed, but I'm trying to install Windows 7.

I can't find a SATA driver on korean LG website, so I can't install Windows 7. If someone gives me a direct download link it would be ok, but I'm more expecting to give me some advices about how to find a SATA driver to any device. I had the same problem with other laptop, but found a link on some forum.

I know I can do it other way like connecting HDD to other PC and then starting the installation and after restart I can connect it again to my laptop etc, but I'm only interested about finding the right SATA driver.

Comment: From what I gather, this notebook has a M.2 SSD. It may or may not use NVMe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do that:

1. Go to the manufacturers website. Select your laptop model, go to the driver section and download the drivers (e.g. to an USB pen drive). Then during installation choose to load additional drivers. Swap the pendrive with windows 7 install for the one with the driver. Load it **and swap back**.
   In your case this did not work, but I hope you copied all relevant specs before you wiped windows 10 (or made a disk image so you could go back and check).
2. Look in the motherboard manual and check which chipset is used. In almost all modern laptops the SATA controller is part of the chipset. Load the relevant driver.
3. Failing those first two, boot any OS (e.g. linux from a live CD, or a windows live CD) and get the PCI hardware IDs. How to translate those to actual hardware is already descriped on [Su]. Then download the relevant drivers to a pen drive.

Windows (and Linux and modern BSDs and ...)  usually ships with a lot of build in drivers though. I am rather surprised if it did not recognize a normal AHCI SATA controller. But if the firmware (EFI) is configured for fake RAID then you probably will run into problems and you will need drivers. Solution: Set the SATA controller to the AHCI mode.

---

OK, so much for generic answers which will help most of the people reading this post. Now to you specific question:

I can not dind the specs on-line (or maybe I did, but I am not able to read Korean), but I understand that the CPU is a [i5-6200U](http://ark.intel.com/products/88193/Intel-Core-i5-6200U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_80-GHz?q=%20I5-6200U).

That is a low power Broadwell-U  chip build with 14 nm technology. That means is is rather recent. It probably shipped with a recent shipset. One more modern than accounted for with the windows 7 DVD.

Answer (score 1):

Or try Windows 7 media from Maher's digital wirld or murphy78(Google them) with slipstreamed SATA drivers. They have multiple revisions and you can choose the one that corresponds with you license.